# jqGrid does not display data from server

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to display data from server on my jqGrid. it works fine to get data but does not show anything.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<link href="css/jqGrid.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<table id="mapGrid"></table>
<div id="mapGridPager"></div>
```

Js

```
function initGrid() {

    var gridOption = {
        caption: 'Locations',
        url: 'report/search?',
        height: '500', 
        width: '500', 
        colNames:['Event ID', 'DateTime','Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Address'], 
        colModel:[ {name:'eventId', index:'eventId', align:'center',    width:40, fronzen:true}, 
                   {name:'timestamp',index:'timestamp', align:'center', width:100, fronzen:true},   
                   {name:'latitude',index:'latitude', width:100},
                   {name:'longitude',index:'longitude', width:100},
                   {name:'address',index:'address', width:200}
                   ], 
        emptyrecords: 'Nothing to display',
        rowNum:30, 
        mtype: "GET", 
        rownumbers: true, 
        gridview: true, 
        page : 1,
        pager: '#mapGridPager', 
        sortname: 'eventId', 
        viewrecords: true, 
        sortorder: "asc", 
        shrinkToFit: false,
        beforeRequest: function(){
            return false;
        }
    };

    $('#mapGrid').jqGrid(gridOption)
                 .navGrid(gridOption.pager,    {edit:false,add:false,del:false,refresh:false,search:false});

}
```

JSON data

```
{
    "total":1,
    "page":1,
    "records":22,
    "rows":[
        {
            "eventId":1,
            "accountId":"demo",
            "deviceId":"demo",
            "timestamp":"16-01-1970 02:20:25",
            "statusCode":61714,
            "latitude":38.4465157985687,
            "longitude":-121.857991218567,
            "altitude":19.0,
            "address":"Dixon, CA"
        },
       //21 more
    ]
}
```

Event ID of each record is unique.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You should don't forget to include `js/i18n/grid.locale-XX.js` (like `grid.locale-en.js`) *before* `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. I recommend you additionally include options `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "eventId"}` and `loadonce: true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default datatype for Jqgrid is XML, you have to explicitly mention the data type of your data. add the below option, it should display the grid.

datatype: "json".

Jqgrid uses Jquery UI css for themes, so add Jquery-Ui.css and themes as well for better look and feel.

Comment: @sunghun I got the answer in first, I was robbed, robbed I say!

Comment: Mark, What do you mean by you were robbed, you meant to say I copied your comments and posted? If that's the meaning I do not give XXXXX about that. I have been using JQGrid from long time and before I post the answer I did not see any responses that's the reason I posted..

Answer (score 0):

Add `datatype: 'json',` as part of the jqGrid setup.

I'm also making the assuming that this Javascript is getting called at some point.

Comment: Mark, What do you mean by you were robbed, you meant to say I copied your comments and posted? If that's the meaning I do not give XXXXX about that. I have been using JQGrid from long time and before I post the answer I did not see any responses that's the reason I posted